# resize event not working on binding function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(window).resize(equalHeight);  
function equalHeight(){
  $(".container").each(function(){
    boxes = $(this).find('.heightHack');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
      Math, boxes.map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
      }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
  });
}
```

The code above I used to equalize `2` div side by side, but it isn't real time update. I'd used the `resize()` method. why?

Comment: what happens when resize? it does nothing as you need?

Answer (score 0):

Window is not resize then content in it changed. Call `equalHeight` after callback where you update your content or use `setTimeout/setInterval` to check divs sizes and fix then.

Try this:

```
function equalHeight(){
  $(".container").each(function(){
    boxes = $(this).find('.heightHack');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(
      Math, boxes.map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
      }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
  });
  setTimeout(equalHeight, 1000);
}

equalHeight();
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle with html/js?